# Error in *ngFor with KeyValuePipe: ngtsc(2322)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, iterable, union-types

I have the following types

```ts
type ParentKeys = "mum" | "dad";
type ChildKeys = "alice" | "frank";

type Parents = {
    [parentKey in ParentKeys]: {
        children: {
            [childKey in ChildKeys]: {
                parent: parentKey;
                key: childKey;
            };
        }[ChildKeys][];
    };
};
```

That is, the inner `child` objects `{ parent, key }` are mounted inside a tree structure, below their resp. parents; all `parent-child` pairings are allowed. For an example check

```ts
const parents: Parents = {
    mum: {
        children: [
            { parent: "mum", key: "alice", },
        ],
    },
    dad: {
        children: [
            { parent: "dad", key: "frank", },
            { parent: "dad", key: "alice", },
        ],
    },
};
```

Now, if I'm using `parents` inside an Angular template

```html
<div *ngFor="let parent of parents | keyvalue">
    <div *ngFor="let child of parent.value.children">
        <div>child {{child.key}} of parent {{child.parent}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the error

```
Type
'(
    { parent: "mum"; key: "alice"; } |
    { parent: "mum"; key: "frank"; }
)[] |
(
    { parent: "dad"; key: "alice"; } |
    { parent: "dad"; key: "frank"; }
)[]'
is not assignable to type
'(
    (
        { parent: "mum"; key: "alice"; } |
        { parent: "mum"; key: "frank"; }
    )[] &
    NgIterable<
        { parent: "mum"; key: "alice"; } |
        { parent: "mum"; key: "frank"; }
    >
) | null | undefined'
.ngtsc(2322)
```

Of course this can be resolved using `$any()`, but obviously something is wrong with my types, or with the `KeyValuePipe`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to the typing done in parents, the following should work:

```js
type Parents = {
    [parentKey in ParentKeys]: {
        children: {
            parent: ParentKeys, key: ChildKeys
        }[];
    };
};
```

The issue was an over-complication in the typing of the children object.

The issue lies in own the `keyvalue` pipe interacts with the `*ngFor`.

The following `html` works:

```html
<div *ngFor="let parent of parents | keyvalue">
  <div *ngFor="let child of parents[parent.key].children">
    <div>child {{ child.key }} of parent {{ child.parent }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main different is that instead of us calling `parent.value`, we call `parents[parent.key]`. Doing so means we obtain the value stored in the original object. This is because the `keyvalue` combined with the `*ngFor` modifies the object, causing it to lose its iterability and raising an error.

Comment: It's not over-complication, it's itentional as I need to restrict the allowed values of `child` and `key` inside the `parent` tree; I described this inside my task. With your type I could for example define `parents.dad.children = { parent: "mum", key: "alice", }`, which makes no sense (for my purposes).

Comment: I updated my answer, to match it. There is no error per say. It is just a side effect of the way the `keyvalue` pipe and the `*ngFor` directive have when they interact with  nesting.

Comment: Thx, but with your change I'm getting the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Parents'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Parents'.ngtsc(7053)`

Comment: I can't find any cause for it to return the error you are mentioning. So I assume there is something I'm not aware. You can find the code in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fyd81e?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: That's odd, I copied every line from your stackblitz, still the same error. Hope someone else has an idea. Thanks for your work anyway.

Comment: What is your angular version and typescript version?

Comment: Versions are: Angular: 15.0.4, Node: 18.12.1, TypeScript: 4.8.4

Comment: I found out that setting `angularCompilerOptions.strictTemplates = false` in `tsconfig.json` (as is set in your StackBlitz) does at least remove the error message. But of course this doesn't actually solve the problem, it may only point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

simply change it like this

```
type Parents = {
  [parentKey in ParentKeys]: {
    children: Array<{
      parent: ParentKeys;
      key: ChildKeys;
    }>;
  };
};
```

Comment: Same here, please see my comment on IDK4real's answer.